# NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type

Tags: java, jboss, jaxb, jboss7.x, resteasy

I am getting the below error even though the RESTEasy JAXB jar - resteasy-jaxb-provider.jar is bundled in the WAR file

```
04:52:54,461 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (default task-1) Failed executing GET /editor/getMetadata/com.karthik.editor.model.EditorAuditEditor: o
rg.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.karthik.SerializedStatusTO of media type: app
lication/xml
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:166)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeJaxrsResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:422)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:111)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:217)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:159)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
```

I have also included jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my WAR to exclude JBoss provided module/jars

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
  <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
        </exclusions>
        <local-last value="true" />
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have deployed the WAR on JBoss 7 EAP. I am currently working on migrating my apps from JBoss 5 to JBoss 7. There is no code change and works fine on JBoss5. Can you please help resolve this issue on JBOSS 7.

Comment: JBoss 5 brings no JAX-RS implementation with it, so you have to bundle it. On the other hand JBoss 7 has an implementation included. If you are using Maven, you might try to set JAX-RS to provided.

Comment: I have bundled the resteasy-jaxb-provider.jar in the WAR

Comment: Yes, I suspect that is the problem. In JBoss 7 it is already there. See the doc: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html_single/#d4e40
Or is there are a reason you do not want to use the included versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
 The issue was the subsystem name. There is no subsystem named “resteasy”, the subsystem is actually named “jaxrs”.
 I updated the subsystem name in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml as shown below :

```
<exclude-subsystems>
   <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
</exclude-subsystems>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you've told your server to send a SerializedStatusTO object back to the client as a response but it doesnt know how to turn that into a string. You need to include a jar that has a MessageBodyWriter for the com.karthik.SerializedStatusTO class or, if this is a class you have made, you need to make and include one yourself.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6952

IIRC if your bean is JAXB annotated it shouldn't need a custom writer though. Could you provide the code for the bean and the method that sends the server response?

Comment: The bean is JAXB annotated. I have included resteasy-jaxb-provider.jar for marshaling and unmarshalling of Java Object to XML. The same code is working fine in JBoss 5. I suspect the issue is with class loading/jar version in JBoss7.

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens if you add the jackson jaxrs providers? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider

i thought resteasy had jaxb providers by defaut but meybe they're getting supressed somehow?

Comment: or actually try using this jaxb provider https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxb-provider

Comment: Jackson jaxrs is for JSON response type. My service sends XML response.

Comment: yeah i know i was more interested in seeing if it would pick up ANY providers